# $(f) = (c)(g)$, where $R$ is a UFD, $c \in R$, $f,g \in R[x]$, and $g$ is primitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Then $IR[x] = \{a_0 + \cdots + a_dx^d \in R[x] \mid a_i \in I \}$ is an ideal of $R[x]$.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $f = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_dx^d \in R[x]$ be a polynomial.

$f$ is a **primitive** if for all prime ideals $\rho$ of $R$, $f \notin \rho R[x]$.

> Let $R$ be a UFD. The **content** of a nonzero polynomial $f \in R[x]$, denoted $\operatorname{cont}_f$, is the $\gcd$ of its coefficients. As any $\gcd$ in an integral domain, it's defined only up to associate relation.
>
> We also know that if $R$ is a UFD, then $f$ is primitive if and only if $(\operatorname{cont}_f) = (1)$.

Now, what I need to prove is that:

> Let $R$ be a UFD, and let $f \in R[x]$. Then if $(f) = (c)(g)$ (where $(c)(g) = (cg)$), with $c \in R$, and $g$ primitive, then $(c) = (\operatorname{cont}_f)$.

I tried some things, but I to no avail (like reducing ideals the equality to $f = ucg$ for a unit $u$ in $R$ and then seeing what can we extract from the equality $a_i = ucb_i$). Right now I don't have any ideas on approaching a proof.

Comment: @user26857 Seems good enough, but why $\gcd(...,ucb_i,...) = uc\gcd(..., b_i, ...)$? I tried to prove it, though.

Comment: @user26857 We prove that $\gcd(ca_1, ..., c_a_n) = c\gcd(a_1, ..., a_n)$. Obviously, $c\gcd(a_1, ..., a_n)$ is a common divisor of $ca_1, ..., ca_n$. The problem is to prove it the the greatest one. So, let $k$ be another common divisor of $ca_1, ..., ca_n$. Then $ca_i = t_ik$. We need to prove that $k = mc\gcd(a_1, ..., a_n)$.

Comment: Did you ever get to solve this? I am also stuck. It doesn't seem like it follows straight from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(f)=(c)(g)$. Then $(f)=(cg)$. So, $f =ucg$ for some unit $u \in R$.

**What is the $\gcd$ of the coefficients of $f$?**

It is the $\gcd$ of the coefficients of $ucg$. Since $g$ is primitive, the $\gcd$ of the coefficients of $ucg$ is $uc$. Thus, the $\gcd$ of the coefficients of $f$ is $uc$.

But since $\gcd$ is defined up to units, then we can say the $\gcd$ of the coefficients of $f$ is just $c$.

So, $(\mathrm{cont}_f) =(c)$.

Answer (score -2):

$\newcommand{\cont}{\operatorname{cont}}$Hint:$f=\cont_f{f\over {\cont_f}}$ and ${f\over {\cont_f}}$ is a primitive polynomial, $f=cg=\cont_f{f\over {\cont_f}}$ where $g$ is a primitive polynomial implies that $c|\cont_f$ and $\cont_f|c$.

Comment: So, $cg = cont_f \frac{f}{cont_f}$. Both $g$ and $\frac{f}{cont_f}$ are primitive, yes, but how it implies that $(c) = (cont_f)$? Surely, $(c)(g)=(cont_f)(\frac{f}{cont_f})$.

Comment: How do you get that $c \mid \mathrm{cont}_f$ and $\mathrm{cont}_f \mid c$? We have $cg=\mathrm{cont}_f{f\over {\mathrm{cont}_f}}$, but this doesn't say $c \mid \mathrm{cont}_f$ and vice versa.